# Resource Manager UI on 8088 is not working while using kerberized Dataproc cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, kerberos, google-cloud-dataproc

Hi I have created a dataproc cluster using the gcloud command mentioned below -

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create spark-kerberos --region=us-central1 --zone us-central1-c --master-machine-type custom-4-15360 --master-boot-disk-size 200 --num-workers 2 --worker-machine-type custom-2-7680 --worker-boot-disk-size 200 --image-version 1.4-debian10 --scopes 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform' --properties "dataproc:kerberos.beta.automatic-config.enable=true" --project $PROJECT_NAME
```

I am enabled automatic kerberos in this cluster. All services are also running while checking through JPS.

```
root@spark-kerberos-m:~# jps
3841 ApplicationHistoryServer
5761 JobHistoryServer
4402 NameNode
3842 ResourceManager
5875 HistoryServer
12276 Jps
646 AgentMain
4059 RunJar
4908 SecondaryNameNode
6318 RunJar
root@spark-kerberos-m:~#
```

Now issue is with the resource manager UI. I am not able to access the UI on port 8088. Meanwhile the UI can be accessible when cluster is created without adding kereberos.

Comment: How did you access the YARN RM UI? What was the error?

Comment: I am trying to access using URI - MasterIP:port in chrome browser. 
And I am getting 
```
This site can’t be reached $IP 
refused to connect.
```

Meanwhile Spark history server UI is accessible.

Comment: Did you try https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/dataproc-gateways?

Answer (score 2):

On a Kerberized cluster the RM UI runs on the HTTPS port 8090

Comment: In this case, will component gateway automatically point to the right port?

Comment: Yes the component gateway will choose the right port.